# How to determine when a page modified with JS is done loading?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a very bare HTML page that loads two JS files.  One of these JS files then goes and loads a varying amount of content into the page.

I'm trying to get the equivalent of `window.onload` for this extra content.  Obviously, `window.onload` actually fires very quickly, when the page is done loading the two JS files.

Any ideas?  I know I can go and attach `onload` events to every image/script/etc on the page, but would rather not...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

EDIT. If the callback won't help [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) should do the job. I've added it to the example.

In this case you need a call back. Are you using a JavaScript library? if so what library?

In your existing code, after you append to the document you need to call a function that can execute the next bit of code.

something like this.

```
//FILE 1
$(function () {

    $('body').append(someHTMLOrDOMNodes);

    //I don't know what your second script does, but you should name this callback something relevant.
    $('#idOfNewContent').load(function() {
        callback();
    });

});

//FILE 2
function callback() {
    //next bit of code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a callback won't help.  I'm trying to figure out when the content in the newly appended HTML is done loading, e.g. images, scripts, stylesheets, etc.

Comment: `.load()` won't work either.  The code would need to be similar to `$('#content').find('img,script,link').allLoaded(cb)`, but unfortunately the actual load event is horribly un-reliable (it doesn't fire at all on cached objects in IE, for instance).

Comment: Ah i see. Well I hope we find you a better solution.